# Old fantasy book with a party finding coloured stones having powers over fire, water, mood

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the name of a book series of which I remember only the following, with Google yielding no results.

- the name of the author starts with a Z
- the main character is a knight in an household with a name sounding like Malachai who goes on a quest with six others guys and girls (a bard, another knight, a priest, etc.) and each of them finds a stone of colour which has a power on various things (like fire, their mood or water) and then they set toward a quest to beat some ancient evil.
- I used to find the book at the local library 10 years ago in France (but it was translated).

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: [Could it be Roger Zelazny?](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/3619.Roger_Zelazny) and  [also here's a list of authors starting with Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_authors#Z)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going from the list of Z authors posted on the comments, my guess is you're referring to David Zindell's *[The Lightstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lightstone?wprov=sfla1)* and its sequels, first published 2001, so the name and date fit.

From Wikipedia:

> Valashu Elahad, seventh and youngest son of the king of Mesh, is one such knight

A knight, as you remember. Not quite named "Malachi", but might be similar, to your ears.

> Eventually his party grows to have seven significant individuals, each with their unique gifts and abilities.

That seems to fit - seven people with different specialities.

There are also magical stones with special powers, called the Gelestei, in gold, silver, red, black and more. And a relevant prophecy too, of course:

> "The seven brothers and sisters of the earth with the seven stones will set forth into the darkness"

Seems like a good fit, right?

Comment: That is it ! Many thanks  ! I had not found this list of authors in my previous search.